# Assign directory listing to variable in bash script over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to ssh into a remote machine, obtain a directory listing, assign it to a variable, and then I want to be able to use that variable in the rest of the script on the local machine.

After some research and setting up all the right keys and such, I can run commands via ssh just fine.  Specifically, if I do:

```
ssh -t user@server "ls /dir1/dir2/; exit; bash"
```

I do get a directory listing.  If I instead do:

```
ssh -t user@server "set var1=`ls /dir1/dir2/`; exit; bash"
```

instead gives an ls error that the directory was not found.  Also of note is that this happens before I am asked for the ssh key passphrase, which makes me think that it's executing locally somehow.

Any idea on how I can create a local variable with a directory listing list of the remote host in a bash script?

Comment: Do you want that variable set on your local machine or on the remote server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply

```
var1=( $(ssh user@server ls /dir1/dir2) )
```

then test it:

```
for line in "${var1[@]}"; do echo "$line"; done
```

That said, I'd prefer

```
ssh user@server find /dir1/dir2 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | 
    xargs -0
```

This will

- deal a lot better with special filenames
- be more flexible (`man find(1)`)
- adding `-type f` to limit to files only

Comment: @l0b0: congrats with your 2^11 reputation !

Comment: In order to show only subdirs, i had to add a `-mindepth 1` to that find :)

Answer (score 0):

Your command in quote is executed before executing the ssh command.  Escaping the single quote should fix

Comment: Just to be clear, that's one of these `, not one of these '.  I did try escaping it with a \ (if that's even how you do it, I'm pretty new to this) but that didn't fix it, though I can't remember the error.  The reason I put it there is because someone once told me I need it to make stuff into lists to loop through :) .