# How to use the for loop with "here document" over SSH?

Tags: shell, ssh

As the following shell script,

```
#!/bin/bash

Limit=5

ssh -T root@192.168.0.105 <<'EOF'
    for(( i=1; i<=$Limit; i++))
    do
        echo $i
    done
EOF

ssh -T root@192.168.0.105 <<EOF
    for(( i=1; i<=$Limit; i++))
    do
        echo $i
    done
EOF
```

In the first loop,the "$Limit" was null.But in the second loop,the for loop came across an error.How can I do to resolve it?

Comment: The problem is that the variable is set in your local server, while you want it in the scope of the remote. Check [How can i set a local variable in ssh?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16872630/1983854)

Comment: short answer: you want the unquoted heredoc to take the *local* variable `$Limit`, but escape the *remote* variable `\$i`

Comment: Thanks,it has worked out well when I use "\$i".